# Не могу разобраться в telebot и VK_api

Tags: telegram-bot, telebot

уважаемые знатоки !
Я изучаю программирование на python, стараюсь познать все нюансы написания ботов в телеграм через питон.
В данный момент столкнулся с тем что я зашел в тупик в написании, читать документацию вроде как получается и использовать методы, но вопрос пойдет о другом.

Подскажите пожалуйста где достать хорошую информацию, или по возможности приведите пример.
Суть такая: При отправке в телеграм бот допустим ссылку на аккаунт вконтакте бот отправляет информацию о аккаунте.
Пример:

```
> Пользователь пишет в бот: vk.com/id1
> Бот отвечает на запрос: 
ID: 1
Имя: Павел
Фамилия: Дуров
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот, но не забудь **отключить двухфакторку** у своего вк

```css
import telebot 
import vk_api 

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi("НОМЕР ТЕЛЕФОНА ОТ ТВОЕГО ВК", "ПАРОЛЬ ОТ ТВОЕГО ВК") 

vk_session.auth()  # У твоего вк должна быть выключена двухфакторка, иначе не получится

vk = vk_session.get_api() 

bot = telebot.TeleBot("ТОКЕН БОТА ТЕЛЕГРАМ")

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_text(message):
    if "vk.com/" in message.text.lower():
        id = message.text.lower().split("/")[1] # Парсим сообщение пользователя и получаем всё что после /
        user_get=vk.users.get(user_ids = (id)) # Получаем инфу с id
        user_get=user_get[0]
        first_name=user_get['first_name']
        last_name=user_get['last_name']
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"ID: {id} \nИмя: {first_name} \nФамилия: {last_name}") # Выводим сообщение 

bot.polling() # Зацикливаем бота
```

*Работает только с цифровым ID*[image: Работает только с цифровым ID]